# How to stop Parent Component Re-rendering When dispatching updated Redux properties?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Evening all

I am getting an error on one of my components:-

**Cannot update a component (`GameBase`) while rendering a different component (`ExistingGame`). To locate the bad setState() call inside...**

which I am not too sure how to fix.

I am conditionally rendering ExistingGame based upon redux properties within GameBase, e.g:-

```
if (gameReducer.registered){
    return(
        <>
            <ExistingGame />
            { goBackIcon }
        </>
    )   
}
```

The gameReducer.registered is set via a dispatch in a function which is called from an onClick event in a rendered list in GameBase:-

```
const ActiveGameList = () => (

        <table><tbody>
          {activeGamesArray.map(activeGame => (
            ...
            <td key={`join${activeGame.gameId}`} className="joinGame"> <IconContext.Provider value={{ size:20 }}><div className='joinGameIcon' onClick={()=>{ joinTheGame(activeGame) }}><ImUserPlus /></div></IconContext.Provider></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody></table>
      );

    return(
        <>
            <h1>Existing games</h1>
            <h3>Select game to join:</h3>
            <ActiveGameList />
            <br/>
            { goBackIcon }
        </>
    )
```

The joinTheGame function itself is:-

```
const joinTheGame = async (activeGame) => {
    let gameInfo = {gameId:activeGame.gameId, gameName: activeGame.gameName, bankerPlayerNumber: activeGame.bankerPlayerNumber, forename: activeGame.firstName, surname: activeGame.lastName, gameLive: activeGame.gameLive };
    
    // Grab the players for the selected game before opening either JoinGame or ExistingGame
    await client.query({
        query: GAME_PLAYER_DETAILS,
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        variables: {gameId:gameInfo.gameId}
      })
      .then(result => {
           let players = result.data.allGameMoneyPlayers.nodes;
           gameInfo.players = players;

            if (joinLiveGame){
                dispatch(reJoinGame(gameInfo));  
            } else if (joinPendingGame){
                dispatch(joinGame(gameInfo));
            }
        });
}
```

Everything I have read about this "cannot update a component while rendering a different component" error seems to suggest it can be solved by placing the state changing call within  a useEffect hook but I am not sure how to go about this here.

Trying to place useEffect around rejoinGame dispatch just gives me a "React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback" error.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That error typically means you have some `setState` call being unconditionally called during the render cycle. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] so it's clear what is dispatched, and when and where?

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your comment.

You are of course completely correct in that it was a state update causing the issue. As per my question, I had thought there may be some way to wrap the component call with useEffect to stop the bubbling but I think I was off with that.

In the end I solved the issue by adding new a "in game" reducer which stopped changes to the existing game reducer (which additionally held info re the user's relationship with the game, e.g. registered / in game) causing a state change in the GameBase component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone lands up here with similar problems, it turned out my issue was really to do with my redux reducer in my GameBase component. At the GameBase level, I'm really managing the user's relationship with the game, so have something like:-

```
const gameReducer = (state = [], action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case "SET_GAME":
        return {
            registered: true,
            inGame: true,
            game: {...action.payload}
        }
    case "JOIN_GAME":
            return {
                registered: false,
                inGame: true,
                game: {...action.payload}
            }
    case "REJOIN_GAME":
        return {
            registered: true,
            inGame: true,
            game: {...action.payload}
        }    
    ...

    default: return state
}
```

The SET_GAME action was additionally being called via my ExistingGame component and although the registered / inGame properties (which are used to decide if GameBase renders ExistingGame or another component) weren't being changed, the change to the actual game data in ExistingGame was causing that property change to be picked up in GameBase and causing a re-render. Hence the error.

I resolved this by creating a new reducer specifically to handle just the game data, via SET_GAME, and setting my dispatch to that, in the ExistingGame component.

In short - human error! Although it's worth noting that if you encounter this error it may not be a case of looking through specifically for setState()s in your child component.